# Typescript - How to get all class properties with decorators from a class decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, reflect-metadata

I want to have a class decorator that gets a list of all properties with a certain decorator and then modify the class to add some additional properties. For example:

```
@CheckForPropertyThings
export class FoorBar {
  @PropertyThing hello: string;
}
```

In this example, I want to check the class for all properties with the `PropertyThing` decorator and then modify the class to add certain properties. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can typescript property decorators set metadata for the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281045/can-typescript-property-decorators-set-metadata-for-the-class)